Why does the blue loop occur?
I understand that the blue loop is a loop in the HR diagram performed by stars from 2-8 solar masses. I was curious as to why they occur, but when I researched all I got is that it is when the star begins to fuse helium. However, these stars do not undergo a helium flash as their cores are not degenerate.

Stars above about 2.3 M$_\odot$ smoothly ignite helium in their core before reaching the tip of the red-giant branch and become hotter while they burn helium in their cores, thus entering the blue loop.
However, there are also other stars that may experience blue loops, some of them more than once, see Wikipedia for a decent explanation.
